# typedef struct commands differences

Tags: c

Is there any difference between:
`typedef struct{~} name` and `typedef struct xxx{~} name` ?

I think the latter is the official one but I am not sure which one is preferred.

I also have seen `typedef tag_name{} name` so it's really confusing to differentiate differences among these syntax forms.

Answer (score 2):

no difference.
You need the intermediate name (xxx in your example) in case you need a reference to the struct within the struct itself. a classic example for this  is linked list

Comment: Thank you! I was about to ask a question regarding that struct keyword used inside struct in linked list. Is it for creating a variable inside a structure?

Comment: `regarding that struct keyword used inside struct in linked list` - `struct xxx { struct xxx *pnt; }` creates a pointer inside the structure. But you can do the same with forward declaration with typedef `typedef struct xxx name; struct xxx { name *pnt; }`

Answer (score 2):

Both `typedef struct {…} name` and `typedef struct xxx {…} name` define `name` to be an alias for the structure type. However, the latter also defines `xxx` to be a tag for the structure type, so that `struct xxx` is also a name for the structure type.

In addition to the fact that `struct xxx` is needed if members of the structure are to refer to the structure type (such as declaring a member that is a pointer to the structure type), there are technical differences in the definitions. If `typedef struct {…} name` is used in one translation unit (a source file being compiled, with all of its included files) and `typedef struct xxx {…} name` is used in another translation units, then the type `name` in one translation unit is not compatible with the type `name` in the other translation unit (per C 2018 6.2.7 1).